# Why is it unnecessary to add 1 when mixing quotes in this use case of .slice() and concatenation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, slice, indexof

In [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Useful_string_methods), the section "Making new strings from old parts" gives the task of cutting out undesired data to a achieve human-readable format for train station names.

e.g.

Original string: MAN675847583748sjt567654;Manchester Piccadilly

Desired string: MAN: Manchester Piccadilly

```
const list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
list.innerHTML = '';
let stations = ['MAN675847583748sjt567654;Manchester Piccadilly',
                'GNF576746573fhdg4737dh4;Greenfield',
                'LIV5hg65hd737456236dch46dg4;Liverpool Lime Street',
                'SYB4f65hf75f736463;Stalybridge',
                'HUD5767ghtyfyr4536dh45dg45dg3;Huddersfield'];

for (let i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
  let input = stations[i];
  let code = input.slice(0,3);
  let semiC = input.indexOf(';');
  let name = input.slice(semiC + 1);
  let result = code + ': ' + name;
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = result;
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

My solution:

```js
let stations = ['MAN675847583748sjt567654;Manchester Piccadilly',
                'GNF576746573fhdg4737dh4;Greenfield',
                'LIV5hg65hd737456236dch46dg4;Liverpool Lime Street',
                'SYB4f65hf75f736463;Stalybridge',
                'HUD5767ghtyfyr4536dh45dg45dg3;Huddersfield'];
for (let i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
  let input = stations[i];
  let stationAbbr = input.slice(0,3);
  let semicolon = input.indexOf(';');  
  let stationName = input.slice(semicolon);
  let station = stationAbbr + ': " + stationName;
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = station;
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

Tutorial solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
  let input = stations[i];
  let code = input.slice(0,3);
  let semiC = input.indexOf(';');
  let name = input.slice(semiC + 1);
  let result = code + ': ' + name;
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = result;
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

The tutorial's construction of `result` is functionally equivalent to my `station`.

As you can see, however, I made the mistake of mixing single/double quotes when declaring `station`.

This actually yields the desired outcome, but fixing the quotes adds a semicolon in middle of the output.

Why does mixing quotes *here* remove the need to specify `+ 1` in `stationName` and `name`?

Comment: *This actually yields the desired outcome* Not really, your code results in a SyntaxError: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token @ JS line 11` If you begin a string literal with `'` or `"`, you must also end it with `'` or `"`

Comment: @CertainPerformance fair enough, I do understand that quotation marks around strings must match, but I guess it must be a quirk of the code involved in the tutorial box.

Comment: Yes, that's my username...?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I hit enter :( Boy, you sure are quick, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to the tutorial, your code block isn't valid javascript and not working. You can confirm this by pasting the code in the console. Starting a string with ' requires it to finish with '. Using " hasn't signalled for it to end the string and instead becomes part of it.

The tutorial input window doesn't seem to alert you of any errors or update the output when the code cannot execute. I can replicate your issue by selecting show the solution then pasting your code over it. The correct answer remains but that it due to the solution code.

That + 1 is needed to select the character after the semicolon, which will be the start of the station name.

Comment: I don't think it's due to the solution code, because on other examples, clicking "hide solution" will display the output of the associated code. You are correct that the tutorial box does not throw errors, but it will typically display nothing if code is invalid.

Comment: It could be an issue with how the webpage converts the input into executable JavaScript too?